# How to use placeholders prefix in flyway command line

Tags: flyway

Originally posted in https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2429

I have an issue (probably a wrong configuration) using flyway placeholders; I can use placeholders for my own variables; but it fails cos one value in an sql query has a similar syntax as flyway placeholder syntax.

**Which version and edition of Flyway are you using?**

`5.2.4 using official docker image`

**If this is not the latest version, can you reproduce the issue with the latest one as well?** (Many bugs are fixed in newer releases and upgrading will often resolve the issue)

`5.2.4` tag is the latest version in docker hub (https://hub.docker.com/r/boxfuse/flyway/)

**Which client are you using? (Command-line, Java API, Maven plugin, Gradle plugin)**

Command line thru the docker image

**Which database are you using (type & version)?**

`MySQL Server version: 5.7.26 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)` - This is a legacy project

**Which operating system are you using?**

`Linux CentOS 7 x64` (uname -r = `3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64`)

**What did you do?**

(Please include the content causing the issue, any relevant configuration settings, the SQL statement that failed (if relevant) and the command you ran.)

I apply flyway to initialize/update a MySQL database; here are a couple of SQL commands.

Here I use placeholders with xxx prefixes:

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS '${xxxdbuser}'@'${xxxdbclip}' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '${xxxdbpass}';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${xxxdbbase}.* TO '${xxxdbuser}'@'${xxxdbclip}';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

... then in another SQL script, from a thirdparty app, I insert a content with `${row}`. I don't want Flyway to interpret `${row}` as a placeholder, only my own vars starting by `${xxx` such as `${xxxdbuser}`

```
INSERT INTO `xxx_xxx` (`name`, `template`, `lang`, `group`, `version`, `data`, `size`, `style`, `modified`) VALUES
... ('addressbook.email.rows', '', '', 0, '1.3.001', 'a:1:{i:0;a:6:{ ... \"label\";s:21:\"$row_cont[type_label]\";s:4:\"name\";s:12:\"${row}[type]\";s:5:\"align\";... :{i:0;s:4:\"100%\";}}}', '100%', '', 1150326789), ...
```

I guess the placeholderPrefix parameter described into https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/info or FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDER_PREFIX env var described into https://flywaydb.org/documentation/envvars#FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDER_PREFIX is for that purpose; but I didn't succeed in using them!

Here is my command using docker:

```
docker run --rm --network="$(docker network ls --filter name=app_mysql_dev --filter "label=type=app" --format '{{.ID}}')" \
    -v `pwd`/code/Admin/install:/flyway/sql \
    -e FLYWAY_URL=jdbc:mysql://${host}:${port}?useSSL=false \
    -e FLYWAY_SCHEMAS=${base} \
    -e FLYWAY_USER=root \
    -e FLYWAY_PASSWORD=${root_pwd} \
    -e FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDERS_PREFIX="\${xxx" \
    -e FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDERS_XXXDBBASE=${base} \
    -e FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDERS_XXXDBUSER=${user} \
    -e FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDERS_XXXDBPASS=${pass} \
    -e FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDERS_XXXDBCLIP=${clip} \
    -e FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDERS_XXXVHOST=${vhost} \
    -e FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDERS_XXXSCHEME=${scheme} \
    -e FLYWAY_CONNECT_RETRIES=5 \
    boxfuse/flyway:5.2.4 -locations=filesystem:/flyway/sql/custom/ \
    migrate
```

**What did you expect to see?**

All `${xxx` placeholders should be replaced by their corresponding ENV values; and the `${row}` chain in SQL code stay unchanged.

**What did you see instead?**

Flyway error:

```
Flyway Community Edition 5.2.4 by Boxfuse
Database: jdbc:mysql://tasks.atlas-mysql:3306 (MySQL 5.7)
ERROR: No value provided for placeholder expressions: ${row}.  Check your configuration!
```

I guess I did not configure my command correctly... any help, advise and/or command line example would help.

Regrads,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a couple of problems in your command:

`-e FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDERS_PREFIX="\${xxx"`

should be `FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDER_PREFIX` (no S), and

`-e FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDERS_XXXDBBASE=${base}`

should be `FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDERS_DBBASE` (as XXX is part of the prefix, it's not included in the placeholder name; and analogously for following lines).

Comment: Thanks Julia, works like a charm with your comments.